# Update XML XNode value in wp7

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, isolatedstorage

hello friends i need some help about updating xml node in wp7. my xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigData>
  <CallerNo1>123</CallerNo1>
  <MobileNo1>123</MobileNo1>
  <MobileNo2>123</MobileNo2>
  <MobileNo3>123</MobileNo3>
  <MobileNo4>123</MobileNo4>
  <MobileNo5>123</MobileNo5>
  <EmailNo1>123</EmailNo1>
  <EmailNo2>123</EmailNo2>
  <EmailNo3>123</EmailNo3>
  <EmailNo4>123</EmailNo4>
  <EmailNo5>123</EmailNo5>
</ConfigData>
```

i want to update  value to 1111 so i wrote following code to achieve it :

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Configuration.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(isoFileStream, LoadOptions.None);
                    xml.Element("ConfigData").SetElementValue("CallerNo1", "11111");
                    xml.Save(isoFileStream);
                    isoFileStream.Flush();
                    isoFileStream.Close();
                }
```

then after i read file again it shows xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigData>
  <CallerNo1>123</CallerNo1>
  <MobileNo1>123</MobileNo1>
  <MobileNo2>123</MobileNo2>
  <MobileNo3>123</MobileNo3>
  <MobileNo4>123</MobileNo4>
  <MobileNo5>123</MobileNo5>
  <EmailNo1>123</EmailNo1>
  <EmailNo2>123</EmailNo2>
  <EmailNo3>123</EmailNo3>
  <EmailNo4>123</EmailNo4>
  <EmailNo5>123</EmailNo5>
</ConfigData><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigData>
  <CallerNo1>11111</CallerNo1>
  <MobileNo1>123</MobileNo1>
  <MobileNo2>123</MobileNo2>
  <MobileNo3>123</MobileNo3>
  <MobileNo4>123</MobileNo4>
  <MobileNo5>123</MobileNo5>
  <EmailNo1>123</EmailNo1>
  <EmailNo2>123</EmailNo2>
  <EmailNo3>123</EmailNo3>
  <EmailNo4>123</EmailNo4>
  <EmailNo5>123</EmailNo5>
</ConfigData>
```

new xml is created and appended to existing xml what should be done to change the xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you call `Save(Stream)` on the `XmlDocument` instance you are writing to the end of the `isoFileStream` you need to reset the position in the stream to write over what is already there.

The easiest way to do this is to create a new `IsolatedStorageFileStream` for writing:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    XDocument xml = null;
    //Read the file stream into an XDocument using a reading stream
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Configuration.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        xml = XDocument.Load(isoFileStream, LoadOptions.None);
        xml.Element("ConfigData").SetElementValue("CallerNo1", "11111");
    }

    //Write it back out using a write one.
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Configuration.xml", FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        xml.Save(isoFileStream, SaveOptions.None);
    }
 }
```

Comment: how to get particular xnode value ??

Comment: You should use the Element/s to get XElements the get the values from there.

Comment: xml = XDocument.Load(isoFileStream, LoadOptions.None);
IEnumerable<XElement> childList = from el in xml.Elements("ConfigData") select el;
foreach (XElement ele in childList)
{
 MessageBox.Show(ele.Value);
}     this isn't working...

Comment: XmlNodeList not supported on wp7 ?

Comment: You need xml.("ConfigData").Elements() in the above example.